# The form does not submit the selected value of the <s:select>

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have the following dropdown list which **correctly shows the options but** when I select an item and submit the form it runs into the following error :

```
'select', field 'list', name 'name': The requested list key 'listnames' could not be 
 resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or 
 people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

My JSP form

```
      <s:form method="POST" action="addNames">
            <s:select name="name"
                      label="Names"
                      list="listnames"
                      />
     </s:form>
```

My Action

```
 @Action
 public class Myaction implements ModelDriven{
    private MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    private List listnames = new ArrayList();

   @Override
   public MyClass getModel() {
      return this.myclass;
   }

  public List getListnames() {
     return listnames;
  }

  public void setListnames(List listnames) {
     this.listnames = listnames;
 } 


   public MyClass getMyClass() {
       return myclass;
 }

   public void setMyClass(MyClass myclass) {
       this.myClass = myclass;
   }
 }
```

My Class

```
 public class MyClass {
   private String name;

   ..... getter and setters go here ....
 }
```

struts

```
<package name="MyUsers" extends="default" namespace="/MyUsers">
        <action name="*" method="{1}" class="com.myproject.controller.Myaction">
            <result name="uAdd" type="tiles" >uAdd</result>
            <result name="uView" type="tiles" >uView</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your select tag like this

```
 <s:form method="POST" action="addNames">
            <s:select name="myclass.name"
                      label="Names"
                      list="listnames"
                      />
     </s:form>
```

**Edit:**

**Problem:**
I guess you are hitting jsp directly hence there is no any action execution. If there is no any action execution then there is no any list in request.

**Solution.**
Hit URL in way that action class get executed and list should initialize or populated before rendering the jsp or view.

Create a method like **populateView** in action class and execute this method rather than directly execution JSP.

Hope you understand what I want to say.

Comment: Can you post your configuration file.

Comment: question is updated, please not it shows the values but run into error when I select a value and submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1** :make sure that getter and setter for `listnames` are done properly

**STEP 2** :make sure that you have done the declaration and initialization for `listnames` List properly

**UPDATE 2**
Sample Example

***struts.xml***

```
<action name="getText" class="commonpackage.ReportsCommonClass" method="getText">
<result name="success">index.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="myaction" class="commonpackage.ReportsCommonClass" method="myaction">
<result name="success">index2.jsp</result>
</action>
```

***index.jsp***

```
 <s:form id="conform" action="myaction" method="post">
 <label>NAME</label>
     <s:select id="name1" name="name1" list="mylist" headerKey="0" headerValue="--SELECT--"/>              

<s:submit value="Click" />  
 </s:form>
```

***In commonpackage.ReportsCommonClass class***

```
ArrayList mylist=new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList getMylist() {
        return mylist;
    }

    public void setMylist(ArrayList mylist) {
        this.mylist = mylist;
    }

  public String getText()
  {
      mylist.add("NAME 1");
       mylist.add("NAME 2");
        mylist.add("NAME 3");
         mylist.add("NAME 4");
          mylist.add("NAME 5");
       return SUCCESS;
  }
  String name1;

    public String getName1() {
        return name1;
    }

    public void setName1(String name1) {
        this.name1 = name1;
    }


  public String myaction()
  {
       System.out.println("NAMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE:"+name1);
       return SUCCESS;
  }
```

Comment: step1 is done step 2 also is done as it shows the options but does not retrieve the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Provide getter setter for name in your action class.
As your select tag name is name `<s:select name="name">` when you submit your form it will search for the property name in your action class.
This may be the problem in your case

Comment: As I have explained in the question it shows all the options the problem is not receiving the value of selected option.

Comment: I have defined private String name and defined its getter and setter but still run into same error.